# Raspbian: Can't see newly created file in /boot on sd card

Tags: linux, systemd, raspbian, sd-card

I am trying to copy a file from the boot directory for a rasbian image in it's boot directory. I would like to write once to the sd card and not have to run rasbian for the file to be in the /home/pi directory.

I have a custom configuration file that I would like to copy over during startup, preferably into /home/pi. I put the sd card into my computer and dropped this into the boot directory.

The issue is that the file isnt visible in /boot when I boot up the pi and ssh into it. I am putting a file named config.txt into the /boot directory (next to wpa_supplicant and ssh files).

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this? I know I can put the file in there manually but I would like to not have to ssh in to do so, would like to just drop it onto the sd card after writing the image with etcher.

Comment: What OS are you attempting to copy the file from? You should be able to mount the root filesystem and copy the file to that.

Comment: _"I am putting a file named config.txt into the /boot directory (next to wpa_supplicant and ssh files)."_ ... `wpa_supplicant` and `ssh` typically are in `/etc` so I'm really confused by your description. Please describe your context in more detail...

Comment: @torin It is using raspbian (a flavor of linux for the raspberry pi). you can see for instance here how you can drop files into the boot directory on the sd card which are copied over on launch .https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/prepare-sd-card-for-wifi-on-headless-pi

Comment: @timmyg13 I meant the OS used when "writing the image with etcher.". You may be able to immediately mount the root partition from the sdcard and copy your file directly to `home/pi`.

Comment: @Torin sorry - am using OSX

Comment: @Torin would prefer to write once and drop some files (similar to the ssh and wpa_supplicant) and have something in the raspbian OS pull it in if possible. May be impossible, apologies for my lack of partition, mounting, etc. understanding. Figured it may be possible if it can do it for these other files.

Comment: @timmyg13 Does it work writing to `/boot` but calling it something other than `config.txt`? `/boot/config.txt` has a [special meaning](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/) with the raspberry pi

Comment: @Torin i dont see any files that I put in there. I tried .env, environment.txt, env.env, etc.